# How do I preserve creator / assignment / commenter associations when a self-hosted GitLab export is imported on GitLab.com?

Tags: gitlab

I have a handful of projects on a self-hosted GitLab instance which I am losing the ability to use.  I've decided to moved these projects to GitLab.com, in part because of how easy I expect the migration process to be.  Since it is GitLab on both sides, I hoped that the imported project would be essentially indistinguishable from the exported project.

I have exported the projects from the GitLab instance where they were previously hosted.  I have also done a couple trial imports onto GitLab.com.

First, I tried importing a project with no other setup.  I used GitLab.com's big green "New Project" button, selected "Import project", selected "GitLab export", and provided a project name and the export .tar.gz file.

The import seemed largely successful but with one significant shortcoming.  Every issue is marked as having been reported by me.  Every issue is assigned to me.  Every comment is marked as having been made by me - but with an extra line at the end explaining who actually made the comment.

This clearly failed to meet the hopes I described at the top - since ownership and authorship history has been practically destroyed.

Next, I had one of my collaborators on the original self-hosted GitLab instance create a GitLab.com account.  I also had them associate the same email they used in the self-hosted GitLab instance with their GitLab.com account.  Then I followed the same import process.

The outcome of this import was largely indistinguishable from the first attempt.

Is it possible to preserve ownership and authorship information for this kind of migration?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to independently perform "User Mapping" for an import into GitLab.com.  Instead, GitLab.com support needs to be engaged to perform the import.

This is because the "Administrator" access level required by GitLab is not available to any customers of GitLab.com.

However, as of March 31st, 2021, GitLab.com support is so overwhelmed that after almost three months of waiting for them to perform this import for my projects, they have closed my support request essentially as "won't fix" because "we're too busy".

Thus, in practice, it is not possible to perform this User Mapping on GitLab.com *at all*.

https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/support/workflows/importing_projects.html#user-mapping